# How to use PowerShell as admin on Hyper.js

Tags: powershell, console

I'm trying to use PowerShell with Hyper.js. I have this on the hyper config file:

```
shell: 'powershell.exe',
shellArgs: ['']
```

This way PowerShell is loaded as non-admin, and I receive an error because I don't have a PowerShell profile file configured, but I have a profile for admin user, I want to configure Hyper.js to use PowerShell as admin.

Comment: Why not just create a profile script for the user account running Hyper.js?

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best solution, but you can run Hyper as admin
https://github.com/zeit/hyper/issues/1752#issuecomment-427086434

There are some other solutions in the linked issue.